# How to print a negative number as 0?

Tags: c++

For class I've made a turn based fighting game that keeps track of the user's health with: `Player.HP = 100;` (inside a structure)

It's printed with `cout << "Health: " << Player.HP << endl;`

The do while loop is exited once their health or the computer opponents health is equal or less than 0

```
} while ((Player.HP >= 0) && (com.HP >= 0));
```

If for instance the health is equal to -14 is there a way to have it printed as 0 in a cleaner way than using an if statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write the if statement with [inline if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
cout << "Health: " << (Player.HP >= 0 ? Player.HP : 0) << endl;
```

This prints `Player.HP` if it is greater or equal to zero, and prints zero otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

One way is [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max)...

```
std::cout << "Health: " << std::max(Player.HP, 0) << '\n';
```

Comment: A problem with using `max` is that if `Player.HP` is not `int` this will not compile  .. so you have to do something ugly such as static_cast the `0` to the type of `HP`.

Comment: @M.M. good point, though `static_cast` is a bit excessive - can use a 0 literal of the appropriate type - e.g. `0.0` for `double`, or `0.0f` for `float`; `max<decltype(Player.HP)>(Player.HP, 0)` is another option if you don't want to check the conversion's safe.

Answer (score 6):

Extract your behavior with a getter function:

```
class Player {
int HP;

public:
    int getHP() const { return HP > 0 ? HP : 0; }
}
```